# Using elisp code with table formula problem

Tags: org-table

I've got these working

```
#+NAME: expogrowth1
| 1 |   2 |
| 2 |   4 |
| 3 |   8 |
| 4 |  16 |
| 5 |  32 |
| 6 |  64 |
| 7 | 128 |
| 8 | 256 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2..@$2> = @-1$2*2
```

and

```
#+NAME: expogrowth2
| 1 | 2 | 3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |   7 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32 | 64 | 128 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2..@2$> = @2$-1*2
```

but this won't work

```
#+NAME: expogrowth4
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @2$1..@2$> = '(mapcar (lambda (arg) (expt arg 2)) (list @1$1..@1$>))
```

This is not exactly the same, but eventually I'd like to have a real exponential growth table working with the elisp version. I'm following [this](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-spreadsheet-lisp-formulas.html), and the code from it works, but my own code to simply square the numbers from the top row won't work, and I can't see why.

Comment: The `elisp` tag does not mean what you think it means (and there is a pending edit to remove it): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things: yes, there is a string conversion problem as @db48x has pointed out in his answer, but assuming that the last table should produce the same results as the other two, the formula is much simpler:

```
#+TBLFM: @2$1..@2$> = '(expt 2 (string-to-number @1))
```

In words: for every cell in the second row, get the corresponding cell in the first row (a string), convert the string to a number and then raise 2 to that exponent.

What your formula would do (after fixing the string conversions) would be to assign a *list* of values to each cell in the LHS range.

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula debugger; you can turn it on with `C-c {`. You’ll see something like this:

```
Substitution history of formula
Orig:   '(mapcar (lambda (arg) (expt arg 2)) (list @1$1..@1$7))
$xyz->  '(mapcar (lambda (arg) (expt arg 2)) (list @1$1..@1$7))
@r$c->  '(mapcar (lambda (arg) (expt arg 2)) (list #("1" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("2" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("3" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("4" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("5" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("6" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("7" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table))))
$1->    '(mapcar (lambda (arg) (expt arg 2)) (list #("1" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("2" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("3" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("4" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("5" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("6" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table)) #("7" 0 1 (fontified t face org-table))))
Result: #ERROR
Format: NONE
Final:  #ERROR
```

You can see that the arguments are substituted in as strings, and fontified strings at that. You’ll need to convert them to numbers before you can call `expt` on them. The document you’re reading gives several different ways to do that; which one is best for you depends on what you’re trying to do.